# Android Eclipse - how to call the variable given to the button created by another button

Tags: android, database, eclipse, button, textfield

I'm new in Eclipse, I'm trying to make an android application that if I click the "Create Button" it will create a textfield and another button that has an ID(ID+1 for every click in "Create Button")

If i click the created button, anything written in textfield will get saved in the database.

This is my code

```
   package com.example.pmkrj;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.app.Dialog;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.LinearLayout;
   import android.widget.TextView;

    public class monitortask extends Activity {
    Button bb11;
    EditText tf1;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params ;
    LinearLayout linearlayout ;
    int i = 0 ;
    String m = "Monitor Task", td = "Save!";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.monitortask);
        bb11 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bb1);
        linearlayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_lay);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,                                                                  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 5);
        bb11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)`enter code here` {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tf1 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                bb11 = new Button (getApplicationContext());
                bb11.setText(String.valueOf(m + " " +1));
                bb11.setText(String.valueOf(td));
                bb11.setId(i+1);
                ++i ;
                linearlayout.addView(tf1, params);
                linearlayout.addView(bb11, params);


            }
        });
        }

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            bb11 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bb1);
            bb11.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
            switch (arg0.getId()) {
            case R.id.bb1:
                boolean didItWork = true;
                try {
                        String date = tf1.getText().toString();
                        String task = bb11.getText().toString();

                    Member entry = new Member(this);
                    entry.open();
                    entry.createInfo(date, task);
                    entry.close();
                } catch (Exception e ) {
                    didItWork = false;

                    Dialog d  = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Sorry!");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("\tFailed");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }finally {
                    if (didItWork) {    
                        Dialog d  = new Dialog(this);
                        d.setTitle("Awesome!");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("\tSuccess");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();

                }   
            }
            break; 
            }
       }
  }
```

Comment: whta is your quextion?

Comment: i edited my post, kindly check it again.

Comment: still not getting what your question is, what trouble you are facing implementing all that you want to.

Comment: I dont know how to call the given ID by bb11.setId(+1), so when I click the button given by "Create Button" the written text in the textfield will get saved in the database, my problem now is when I click the given button its do nothing